# DRF query the foreign key value with filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to query the foreign key value with filter condition in django rest framework. I'm retrieving the value by DRF StringRelatedField method, but i don't have any idea how to filter while query itself

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class Score(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='score', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   score = models.FloatField(null=False)
```

serilizer.py

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    score = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'score', )
```

views.py

```
class UserDetailsRetrieveViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     def list(self, request):
         queryset = User.objects.filter(score>=10)
         serializer = UserDetailsSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some examples of code? What you tried and what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you need to filter `User` objects while viewing the API and your API is `/api/v1/user/`. This filtering can be achieved by two ways,

1: Using **django queryset filter**
You must pass the filter parameter through URL like this, `/api/v1/user/?score=10`. re-write your view like following,

```
class UserDetailsRetrieveViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        score = request.GET.get('score', None)
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        if score:
            queryset = queryset.filter(score__gte=score)
        serializer = UserDetailsSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

2. Using **[django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/) package**
If you are trying to use the package, do not forget to install it.Your view will be like this,

```
class UserDetailsRetrieveViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  # your queryset
    serializer_class =  # your serializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('score',)

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return User.objects.all()
        else:
            return  # default queryset
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I will try the DjangoFilterBackend package, i have some other filters requirements also like(contains, exact_match in name, email).

Comment: If you have more customized filter option, you can try `filter_class` by writing a customized `filterset` , here is the link http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filter-class